# Posting variable to correct row

Tags: php, android, mysql

Posting a variable to the database has been solved. Still need help posting to the correct row.

What i am trying to do is post a variable to the mysql database. The big problem is getting it to be posted to the correct users row. The user that is logged in.

Below is snippet my quiz activity for maths. At the end of the quiz a dialog box appears. the variable right_answers is being submitted to the database.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
   if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(getApplicationContext())){


uestions.length){
            if(qno==6){
                //If all questions have been answered answer Alert Dialog appears, the user can choose to:
                //Submit score
                //Go to main menu without submitting score
                //Retry

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mathsActivity.this);



                // Submit score button
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Submit Score", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // User pressed YES button. Write Logic Here
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Score Submitted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), MathsMenuActivity.class)); 

                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();     
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com/script.php"); 
                        try { 
                             List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);         
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("right_answers", Integer.toString(right_answers)));         
                             nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));         
                             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); 

                             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 

                        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {         
                             // TODO Auto-generated catch block     
                        } catch (IOException e) {         
                                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block     
                        } 



                }


                });

}
```

From user function class which is stored in a package library is the following block.

It is used to to get the login status.

```
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Finally here is the php responsible for inserting the right_answers in the appropriate column.

```
include 'xxxxx/connect.php';

$right_answers = $_POST['right_answers'];

$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (maths)VALUES('" . $right_answers . "')");
```

Help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to point out that you're vulnerable to SQL injection. You need to escape your input, or drop mysql_* functions all together and start working with PDO or mysqli_*. This has nothing to do with your question however.

Comment: Quick tip: **always** [sanitze user input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php). The way you have it set right now, you may as well post your database username and password to the public.

Comment: what response you get from web services when you insert data? can you use this $res=mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (maths)VALUES('$right_answers')") or die("error :". mysql_error()); try this and see what happen. hope you get correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure without testing it you need to do something like this

```
$sql=mysql_query("INSERT INTO members (maths)VALUES('" . $right_answers . "')");
```

Comment: Brilliant that seem to have solved posting the the variable. Thanks alot! However it post to a new row. not for the user that is logged in.

Comment: Can you make is accepted then please, I need the reputation :)